# Are stored procedures declarative or imperative?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Please read the following example first.

I have a database table named Product and this table has a column named Id whose data type is INT.

I'm writing a stored procedure that adds a new Product. One of the rules of the database is when adding new Product, the id assigned for it must be the smallest integer started from 1, and of course the ids are unique.

For example, if the existent ids are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 then the new Product will have an id of 7. But if the existent ids are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 the new id will be 4.

This is my try:

```
DECLARE @newId INT
SET @newId = 1
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Product.id = @newId)
    SET @newId = @newId + 1
/*Then use this @newId to insert new item into table Product*/
```

But my friend told me this code was not efficient because the query inside the while loop's condition would be evaluated for each iteration.

And this is a part of his code:

```
DECLARE @currentId INT, @lastId INT, @newId INT
SET @lastId = 0

DECLARE idCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Product.id FROM Product ORDER BY Product.id
OPEN idCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM idCursor INTO @currentId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @currentId <> @lastId + 1
            BREAK

        SET @lastId = @currentId
        FETCH NEXT FROM idCursor INTO @currentId
    END

SET @newId = @lastId + 1
CLOSE idCursor
DEALLOCATE idCursor
/*Then use this @newId to insert new item into table Product*/
```

In my opinion, SQL is a declarative language, no matter what we write our codes the DBMS will rearrange them to achieve a good execution plan, so I give the optimization part for the DBMS and try to keep things simple and more readable. Besides, finding the new id is only a small part of the stored procedure.

But in my friend's opinion, when writing stored procedure it becomes an imperative language and the code author takes the responsibility for the code efficiency. And he said what I did was to make things simple for me, not for the system.

So my questions are:

1. Is SQL still or no more declarative when we write stored procedures? Or it's somewhere in the middle?
2. What is considered to be a better practice when writing store procedures: keeping them simple or taking all care of their efficiency?

Comment: Simple answer is **Always** try and write *SET BASED APPROACH* code instead of writing *RBAR* code. It doesn't matter it is declarative or not. `While Loops` and `CURSOR` are pure example of *ROW by ROW* operations we should always avoid it.

Comment: This assumption you state is simply plain wrong, at all times, and in all languages: *"In my opinion, SQL is a declarative language, no matter what we write our codes the DBMS will rearrange them to achieve a good execution plan, so I give the optimization part for the DBMS and try to keep things simple and more readable"*. You must learn to program to the strengths of the language you are using, and away from its weaknesses, **so that the engine can generate the best compiled plan possible**.

Comment: In my point of view one should avoid to use SQL as a "programming language" with declared variables, loops and all this stuff. SQL Server does a great job with SET BASED duties, but is quite poor otherwise. If you want to do something declarative, you could think of CLR, Btw: Is this a real project or just somthing to try around? It would be terribly dangerous to re-use an ID just 'cause there's a gap after a deletion...

Comment: Thank all guys, I've got the point. I'll try my best with SET BASED approach. I'll appreciate much if you guys show me more strengths and weaknesses of SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that every language is a mixture of what you call declarative and imperative.

A person can write bad code (or great code) in any language.  In my opinion, if you want to write great code, you must know the strengths and weaknesses of the language you are writing the code in.

Both code block you show will perform poorly because of the loops involved.  A set based approach to this problem would look something like this:

```
Declare @NewId Int

Select  Top 1 @NewId = RowId
From    (
        Select  Id, Row_Number() Over (Order By Id) As RowId
        From    Product
        ) As A
Where   Id <> RowId
Order By RowId

Select @NewId
```

TSQL has a weakness where loops are involved.  In 99.9% of situations, you would be better off avoiding loops.

Comment: It's good when seeing a concrete example. I'll try to stick with set based approach.

Btw, I've just found out a small bug in your query. It works perfectly when there is a gap in id values but won't work when there is no gap. In this case @newId will be NULL because there is no row whose id is not equal rowId

But, don't worry I've got my own solution using the recommended set based approach. Thank you so much for your explanation.